# Running Total Issue

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

I am very new to C++ and am trying to accomplish a program that will display the following: 
1. A Total of all customer bills
2. Total tax collected
3. A customer count
4. An average customer bill.

The average bill, total tax, & customer count all seem to be working just fine. It's the totalBill variable that is throwing it off I believe. I'll attach the code below, I can't figure it out!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main () {

double mealPrice;
double mealTotal;
double totalBills;
double totalTax;
double mealTax;
double averageBill;

int customerCount = 0;
mealTotal = 0.0;

bool anotherMeal = true;
char response;

while (anotherMeal == true) 
{
cout << "Enter price of your meal: ";
cin >> mealPrice;
cout << endl;
customerCount++;

cout << "Another cusotmer? y/n : ";
cin >> response;        
cout << endl << endl;
if (response == 'n') anotherMeal = false;
} //End While Loop

mealTax = (mealPrice * 0.0575);
mealTotal = (mealPrice + mealTax);
totalBills = (mealTotal += mealTotal);
totalTax = (mealTax + mealTax);
averageBill = (totalBills / customerCount);

cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << right;
cout << "Total Customer Bills :  $ " << setw(8) << right << totalBills << endl;
cout << "Total Tax Collected :   $ " << setw(8) << right << totalTax << endl;
cout << "Customer Count : " << setw(16) << right << customerCount << endl;
cout << "Average Customer Bill : $ " << setw(8) << right << averageBill << endl;
cout << endl;
cout << endl;

return 0;

} //End Main
```

When complied it gives the right numbers only is there is one customer, if more the total will be thrown off. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `mealprice` of older customers are lost

Comment: @KarthikT How can I keep from losing them?

Comment: It shouldnt be that hard to figure it out.. how would you do it in real life?

Comment: If you indent your code conventionally, you'll find that you no longer need those `//End` comments.

Comment: Also, don't use floating point arithmetic with monetary amounts: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 2):

```
totalBills = (mealTotal += mealTotal);
```

This line does not make any sense. You are adding the current bill to the current bill; what you want is to add the current bill to the running total.

```
totalBills += mealTotal;
```

Similar change needs to be applied to `totalTax` as well.

Also, your `while` loop ends too early. For the running total to be running, the calculations need to happen *inside* the loop. Just collecting data in the loop will *not* add the bills to the total.

Comment: The running total is still lost when I make that change. Am I doing something wrong? Thanks for the reply

Comment: @user2297888 Edited and tested this time :)